# Toggle mueve <div> en html jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Resulta que tengo un `div` donde muestro un gif que se va usar para dar la sensacion de carga en un login.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**DIV**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 alerta1">
          <img src="~/Content/images/3 (2).gif" class="cargarGif" />
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cargarGif {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*display:none;*/
}
```

Agregando la linea `display:none;` (Cosa que esta comentada para el ejemplo aca), la cosa es que cuando uso `$('.cargarGif').toggle()` para mostrar el gif oculto mientras hace la validacion de login me lo muestra asi y no originalmente en el centro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es el problema? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema reside en que una imagen es un elemento `inline` por defecto, por lo que no va a tener en cuenta los márgenes automáticos. Para ello, va a ser necesario que la imagen sea de tipo `block` (es por eso por lo que cuando añades `display: block` si que se centra donde tu quieres).

Te recomiendo que cambies el método `toggle` por `toggleClass` ya que con el primero no le vas a poder indicar que quieres que tu imagen aparezca con la propiedad `display: block`. Sin embargo, con la segunda función si que podrás indicarle que quieres que agregue (o quite) una clase concreta en la cual estará dicha propiedad.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
$(".cargarGif").toggleClass("bloque");
```

```css
.cargarGif {
    display: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.bloque{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 alerta1">
          <img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png" class="cargarGif" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Como podrás observar, en este caso la propiedad por defecto he puesto que sea `display: none` pero con la función `toggleClass` le añadimos la clase `bloque` que agrega el `display: block` a la imagen haciendo que esta se centre como esperabas.